# Change span html upon radio selection

Tags: jquery

I have 2 radio buttons. But when the one (check1) is selected, i'd like to change the span.amount html. How would I go about doing that?

```
<input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="type" id="check1" value="0" checked />
<label for="check1">$99.99</label>
<input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="type" id="check2" value="1" />
<label for="check2">None</label>

$('#check1').change(function(){
    $('amount').html('$99.99'));
});

<button class="btn" type="submit">Pay <span id="amount" class="amount">$249.99</span></button>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is the span element? Is the id='amount'?

Comment: post complete html and javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current solutions don't fire the change event when the first radio element is de-selected. Try this instead - [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/X5L2t/1/).

---

**jQuery:**

```
$('input[name=type]').on('change', function(){
    $('.amount').html('$99.99');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="type" id="check1" value="0" checked />
<label for="check1">$99.99</label>
<input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="type" id="check2" value="1" />
<label for="check2">None</label>

<button class="btn" type="submit">Pay <span class="amount">$249.99</span></button>
```

---

I'm guessing what you eventually want to do would be something like [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X5L2t/3/).

```
$('input[name=type]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).prop('value') == 1) {
      $('.amount').html('$99.99');
    }
    else {
      $('.amount').html('$249.99');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this...

```
$('#check1').on('change', function(){
    $('.amount').html('$99.99');
});

 <input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="type" id="check1" value="0" checked />
<label for="check1">$99.99</label>
<input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="type" id="check2" value="1" />
<label for="check2">None</label>

<button class="btn" type="submit">Pay <span class="amount">$249.99</span></button>
```

See this **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bWmU8/)**

Comment: `i'd like to change the span.amount html` he has clearly stated that the span has a class `amount`, If I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

My answer : [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adyJ6/)

Loading the first label on body load.

Then in each change updating amount span.

css:

```
.amount
{
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding:5px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

html:

```
<input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="type" id="check1" value="0" checked />
<label for="check1">$99.99</label>
<input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="type" id="check1" value="1" />
<label for="check2">None</label>
<br /><br />
<span class='amount'>here</span>
```

script:

```
var load_val = $('.radio-check:checked').next('label').text();
$('.amount').text(load_val);
$('.radio-check').change(function() { 
load_val = $(this).next('label').text();
$('.amount').text(load_val); 
});
```